# best mysql table type for a lookup table (heavy read, no write)

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

i have an ip-to-country lookup table. this table is updated max once a month while read to very frequently. i currently have it as innodb. is this the best table type for a table that is pretty much only read from ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with MyISAM.  It doesn't have a lot of the features of InnoDB which makes it a little quicker if you don't need things like transaction and foreign keys.  Also, MyISAM has table-level locking while InnoDB uses row-level locking, which won't make much different for a high-read low-write table.

Wikipedia has a good [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines) of the two table types.